# angularjs: ui bootstrap modal dialog without template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have implemented blueimp file uploading with angular-ui-bootstrap .

```
$modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/upload-panel/upload-panel.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log) {
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            },
        });
```

its working fine but issue is i m not able to drag-drop file until modal become active. 
is there any option in modal dialog to just pass div ID that holds upload panel html 
so using angular ui bootstrap $modal service i can show and hide. 
and when i drag and drop file on document it shows modal dialog with dropped files in it

Comment: Could you rephrase that question?

Comment: basically blueimp provide drag and drop file facility on document. for that blueimp html must be embedded in document where angular ui bootstrap modal limit you to provide html template or inline template in both cases . blueimp html will be embedded in document when modal will be active and that will limit to drag and drop files when MOdal dialog is shown on screen.